# The cohomology of modular curves as a module over the Galois group

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, arithmetic-geometry, modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Consider the modular curve $\pi: X(N) \to X(1)$ where this map has Galois group $G = PSL_2(\mathbb Z/N\mathbb Z)$. In particular, $G$ acts on the singular cohomology $H^1(X(N),\mathbb Z)\otimes \mathbb C$ or in finite characteristic, on the etale cohomology group $H^1(X(N),\mathbb Z_\ell)\otimes_{\mathbb Z_\ell}\overline{\mathbb Q_\ell}$.

Do we know which irreducible representations of $G$ appear in the cohomology and with what multiplicities. Also, we can ask how the action of $G$ interacts with the Hecke operators, for instance. This seems to me to be very classical automorphic stuff but I have no knowledge about this area of math. Are there any friendly references?

Looking at the dimensions, I don't believe it is the regular representation.

Comment: This is classical, but I don't know a reference, One way to calculate this representation is by its character. You can use the fact that the trace of a nontrivial element is $2$ minus its number of fixed points of that element on $X(N)$. For any element that does not have order $2$, order $3$, or is unipotent there are no fixed points but for these special elements there are fixed points, so it's not quite the regular representation.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Thank you! This is exactly the kind of thing I was looking for. The proof seems to be along the same lines as Sawin's suggestion.

Comment: Comment now reposted as an answer.

Comment: You can look at Kato, *$p$-adic Hodge theory and values of zeta functions of modular forms*, (4.9.3) and (4.9.4) for the question of how $G$ interacts with the Hecke operators.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Jared Weinstein's PhD thesis (http://math.bu.edu/people/jsweinst/jswthesis.pdf) is an excellent reference for this kind of thing. See section 3.4 in particular, where he computes the space $S_k(\Gamma(N), \mathbb{C})$ as a $\mathbb{C}[\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/N)]$-module using an equivariant version of the Riemann--Roch formula.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand things correctly: If I wanted to use a similar decomposition for etale cohomology instead, I would have to pass to an algebraic closure, use a comparison theorem with algebraic de rham which in turn by hodge theory is the sum of sheaf cohomology of $H^0(X,\omega)$ and it's dual. Since everything is functorial, this isomorphism also preserves the structure of the group action. Do I have that right?

Comment: Yes, that's right, assuming that by $\omega$ you mean the sheaf of differentials, and you take k=2 in Jared's formulae.

Comment: Yep, that's what I had in mind. Thanks a lot!